# How do I debug Certbot Exit 1?

Tags: docker, nginx, certbot

I am trying to launch a containerized version of my website using Nginx according to these directions

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose
```

This includes a Certbot plugin to provide the certificates.
There are no errors, but when I run

```
docker-compose ps
```

I see this

```
certbot     certbot certonly --webroot ...   Exit 1
```

The problem may  be related to the fact that the first time I ran the code, I got a notice that my domain had a certificate already assigned to it. Do I want to 1) reissue a certificate or 2) do nothing. This makes sense since I had been using a non-containerized version of my website before and had a Certbot certificate. The deployment in these instructions, however, is automated, so I did not even have a chance to answer the question.  Also, I cannot regenerate the error message, so the wording is from memory and not exact.

I am new to this type of deployment so I do not know where to start debugging this issue.  Also, if the problem is related to the above Certbot question, how do I fix it?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can get more information on the problem using

```
docker-compose logs
```

Also, more information on rate limits for Let's Encrypt can be found here

```
https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits
```

In my case, the exact error was:

```
cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed
```

The solution is described here:

```
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/nginx-emerg-bio-new-file-etc-letsencrypt-live-domain-com-fullchain-pem-failed-ssl-errorsystem-libraryno-such-file-or-directory-fopen-etc-letsencrypt-live-domain-com-fullchain-pem-r/106597/2
```